# Zooming a NSBorderlessWindowMask styled NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, resize, zooming

I have an `NSWindow` styled using a `NSBorderlessWindowMask` which has need to be resized, yet I'd like it to zoom between two sizes. As per the Apple documentation, a window not supporting resizing will beep when using to use `NSWindow`'s -`performZoom` method.

Is there a way to actually get the window to zoom using the in-built logic using the window's max size, screen bound restraints, and restoring back to the original window location pre-zoom, that can be used without specifying `NSResizableWindowMask`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot resize borderless window using the in-built logic using the window's max size, screen bound restraints, and restoring back to the original window location pre-zoom, that can be used without specifying NSResizableWindowMask.

If you want to toggle size of borderless window, you can use setFrame:display: method like this -

```
NSRect window = [window frame];

if (window.size.width == 50) {

    [window setFrame:NSMakeRect(50, 50, 500, 500) display:NO];
}
else {
    [window setFrame:NSMakeRect(50, 50, 50, 50) display:NO];
}
```

Comment: I figured, but it was worth a shot. Only this approach does not account for the bounds of the screen, nor the fuzzy logic Cocoa implemented when determining if a window is zooms. I'll go ahead and implement all said logic using NSScreen and the other APIs.

I just wondered if there was something I could override the implementation for to fake zoom is available. I'm going to try messing around with -tryToPerform and such on NSResponder first.